# Copy a folder name into the name of its files

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a folder with the name "Mexico" and inside I have pictures in .jpg  . How do I copy the folder name into the filename.

thats current:

```
Mexico(folder)         
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

thats what I want:

```
Mexico(folder)         
 Mexico1.jpg
 Mexico2.jpg
```

And afterwards cut out the picture files and send them into a different folder called "Pictures" where I have other pictures. And delete the original Mexico folder. Both folders are unrelated. Let's say they are both on the Desktop seperate from each other.

End result:

```
Pictures          
 -Mexico1.jpg
 -Mexico2.jpg
 -other.jpg
 -... .jpg
```

Didn't find a good answer online. Prefer simple solutions, I am newbie. And it should be automated so it can be used for many folders in a row. **All folders have different names i.e 'Mexico', 'Spain'**...It is too many folders & pictures to change the names by hand.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the Mexico folder inside the Pictures folder? Outside? If so where it it in relation to the Pictures folder?

Comment: Pictures folder is outside Mexico. Let's say on the Desktop. They have no connection, just 2 different folders.

Comment: If you can specify the relative location of the two, this could probably be done in one command. So if you have `~/Desktop/Mexico` and `~/Pictures`, something like: `cd ~/Desktop/Mexico; rename -n 's,^,../../Pictures/Mexico-,' *.jpg`

Comment: mexico: /home/user/Desktop/Mexico ; Pictures: /home/user/Desktop/Pictures

Answer (score 3):

If both directories are located in the same parent directory, in `Desktop` as an example, you can use something like:

```sh
cd ~/Desktop
rename -n 's,^(.*)/,Pictures/$1-,' Mexico/*.jpg Spain/*.jpg
```

Note that this doesn't actually do any moving or renaming, it will just show you what will be done. Run the command without `-n` after you verify that everything looks good in the output to do the actual renaming.

Then you can delete these empty directories with:

```
rmdir Mexico Spain
```

Or even just:

```
rmdir */
```

This will fail to delete non-empty directories but delete empty ones.

Comment: Substitution replacement not terminated at line 1, in:
s,^(.*)/,Pictures/$1-                   ; the problem is also that all folders and files have different names, maybe I wasn't clear sry

Comment: @stony56 ah, sorry, there should be a comma at the end, fixed. Is there any pattern at all? At least if all files end with `.jpg`? If not, you'll have to list out the directory names one by one in the command like in the example.

Comment: thanks. no pattern other then .jpg of all files. It's ok this solutions would work for what I described.

Answer (score 1):

In a Bash shell loop with `mv`:

```bash
for f in */*; do
  if [ "${f%/*}" != "Pictures" ]; then
    echo mv -nv -- "$f" "Pictures/${f%/*}${f#*/}"
    fi
  done
```

You'll need to `cd ~/Desktop` then run the loop and finally remove empty directories with `rmdir */` ... Or do all at once:

```bash
{
cd ~/Desktop
for f in */*; do
  if [ "${f%/*}" != "Pictures" ]; then
    echo mv -nv -- "$f" "Pictures/${f%/*}${f#*/}"
    fi
  done
rmdir */
}
```

**Notice** that `echo` is added for a dry-run, so remove it when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

Demonstration:

```
$ tree ~/Desktop
/home/ubuntu/Desktop
├── Mexico
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   └── 2.jpg
├── Pictures
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   └── 2.jpg
└── Spain
    ├── 1.jpg
    └── 2.jpg
$
$
$ {
cd ~/Desktop
for f in */*; do
  if [ "${f%/*}" != "Pictures" ]; then
    mv -nv -- "$f" "Pictures/${f%/*}${f#*/}"
    fi
  done
rmdir */
}
renamed 'Mexico/1.jpg' -> 'Pictures/Mexico1.jpg'
renamed 'Mexico/2.jpg' -> 'Pictures/Mexico2.jpg'
renamed 'Spain/1.jpg' -> 'Pictures/Spain1.jpg'
renamed 'Spain/2.jpg' -> 'Pictures/Spain2.jpg'
rmdir: failed to remove 'Pictures/': Directory not empty
$
$
$ tree ~/Desktop
/home/ubuntu/Desktop
└── Pictures
    ├── 1.jpg
    ├── 2.jpg
    ├── Mexico1.jpg
    ├── Mexico2.jpg
    ├── Spain1.jpg
    └── Spain2.jpg
```

**Notice** that this will not work on hidden files/directories that start with a dot `.` unless you explicitly set Bash's `dotglob` option.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should work.

```
for file in $(find "./$1" -type f);
do
    cp $file "./Pictures/$1$(basename $file)"
    done
```

It goes through the files in the $1 (argument 1) directory, it then *copies* it to the Pictures directory with the prefix of $1. It copies rather than moves to make mistakes reversable. Argument 1 is the *name*, not path, of the directory of the photos and the prefix.

Edited as per [@Dan's suggestion to use quotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507474/copy-a-folder-name-into-the-name-of-its-files/1507492#comment2644989_1507492), which you might want to keep in mind if you get more involved with scripts.

Comment: I am new to scripts but I'll try it and report back later, thanks.

Comment: You should use quotes around your variables in case they contain spaces or other special characters

Comment: @Dan agreed - unfortunately `for file in $(find ...)` introduces word splitting from the get go which no subsequent quoting can undo - see for example [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice)